# Can I use "Class" and "Type" in my OWL Ontology

Tags: owl, protege, protege4

I need to have Class "Class" (within a namespace) and data property "Type" (also within a namespace).

Protege acts funny when I create them.

Answer (score 1):

> I need to have Class "Class" (within a namespace) and data property
>   "Type" (also within a namespace).

That's technically fine, and possible, though it leaves one to wonder why you would need this, since OWL/RDF provide both for you, already.

> Protege acts funny when I create them.

Strange, it always struck me as a humorless piece of software. But seriously, if it doesn't allow that, then that's a bug in Protege. Unless, of course, you haven't told us the whole story and you're trying to do something else against which Protege is warning you.